# Cron job not running ruby script

Tags: raspbian, cron, ruby

I have a cron job running a ruby script, here is crontab

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/ruby /home/pi/runbot.rb
```

permissions look like this

```
pi@pi $ ls -l runbot.rb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 859 Aug 26 14:16 runbot.rb
```

More info

```
grep cron /var/log/syslog
Aug 26 17:21:42 pi crontab[5278]: (pi) BEGIN EDIT (pi)
Aug 26 17:21:54 pi crontab[5278]: (pi) REPLACE (pi)
Aug 26 17:21:54 pi crontab[5278]: (pi) END EDIT (pi)
Aug 26 17:22:01 pi /usr/sbin/cron[3217]: (pi) RELOAD (crontabs/pi)
```

Some more info

```
tail cron /var/log/syslog
Aug 26 17:23:01 pi /USR/SBIN/CRON[5289]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug 26 17:24:01 pi /USR/SBIN/CRON[5294]: (pi) CMD (ruby /home/pi/runbot.rb)
Aug 26 17:24:02 pi /USR/SBIN/CRON[5293]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Aug 26 17:25:01 pi /USR/SBIN/CRON[5298]: (pi) CMD (ruby /home/pi/runbot.rb)
Aug 26 17:25:02 pi /USR/SBIN/CRON[5297]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Pi model B, rasbian

Comment: what is the script about? sending mails?

Comment: I've verified that cron is calling the ruby script. If I comment almost all of the code out of the script it will run. Or if I just run the script from the command line it runs fine. It just won't run correctly when cron calls it

Comment: OK add `sleep 30; your script` in crontab

Comment: This is definitely a path problem. I just can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with my paths.
Since I am using rvm with ruby I ran

```
rvm cron setup
```

from my working directory to setup my crontab.

I then added the path to my directory to the PATH in crontab made by rvm

Took a day to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is that you have no mailer installed on the Pi.

I think maybe `postfix` can make thinks work here.

```
sudo apt install postfix
```

Also it would be better to analyze any errors in the script by using a subshell and sending the **STDERR** to **STDOUT**.

```
 * * * * * (/usr/bin/ruby /home/pi/runbot.rb) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

if you want to know what `2>&1` means here use [This Reference](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

There might be other options too, instead of `postfix` maybe `mailx` can work too.

```
sudo apt install mailx
```

but you might want to check on that first

Comment: No, that is not the issue.